# Blocking access to application for a user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that use the default ASP.NET Membership Provider.

My customer asked to implement a feature that prevent users to log in (for example for users that resign and leave the company).

I cannot use the IsApproved flag of the Membership table because that field is used to confirm user registration.

Is there any built in functionality for doing this? What are your experiences in scenarios like this?

Comment: Are you using account lockouts?

Comment: @adrift: No. Can I use them for my requirement?

Comment: yes, if IsLockedOut is true, a user will not be able to login until the lockout is cleared.

Comment: @adrift: Do you know the API involved in locking/unlocking a user? Any reference?

Comment: I don't think you can set the `IsLockedOut` flag directly through the Membership API; you would have to write your own code/stored procedure to set it.  Clearing it can be done using the `UnlockUser` method on the `MembershipUser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using account lockouts, you can use the `IsLockedOut` flag for this.  If `IsLockedOut` is `true`, a user will not be able to log in until it is cleared.

For more information on how this property is typically used, see [`MembershipUser.IsLockedOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.islockedout.aspx).

If you want to avoid using `IsLockedOut` for this, and assuming you are using the `SqlMembershipProvider`, another option would be to directly modify the procedure that the provider calls during the login process:  `aspnet_Membership_GetPasswordWithFormat`.

If you check the code for that procedure, you'll see that if the user does not exist, or is locked out, it returns a non-zero result:

```
IF (@UserId IS NULL)
    RETURN 1

IF (@IsLockedOut = 1)
    RETURN 99
```

You could maintain the list of blocked users in a separate table and check against it here.  The downside is that if this procedure is ever recreated or the site is switched to a new membership database, these changes could be lost.

Between these two options, I'd choose using `IsLockedOut`, but I thought I'd add another option in case there was a strong preference against using it this way.

HTH

Comment: You are definitively right. The best option I think is to code a `LockUser` method in my service layer that would expressely try to cause one of the scenario depicted in the remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.islockedout.aspx). Thanks for helping!